# port in vue.config.js is ignored

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I want to develop a Vue app and serve it to external domain.
So I wrote a `vue.config.js` to redirect development server to public like below:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: 8080,
      public: 'mypublicpage.com:8080',
  },
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

Just before few hours ago, I got the expected result of above setting file like this

> App running at:
>   - Local:   http://localhost:8080
>   - Network: http://mypublicpage.com:8080/

But now my Local port is always randomized, so I can't access my Vue app through the public(Network) URL. I still don't know why this happens.

> App running at:
>   - Local:   http://localhost:19282 port changes on every `npm run serve`
>   - Network: http://mypublicpage.com:8080/

Comment: Is there already something running on port 8080?

Comment: @skirtle Sadly, not at all... I checked it just now using lsof and netstat but there is no program uses 8080

Comment: @skirtle Addtionally, I also just rebooted the host but still no progress..

Comment: It is probably not related to your config, as they look just fine. The server normally takes the next available port, but if is randomizing you could have some other process taking the ports